# Creating Drop down List for Create Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have Problem Creating Drop down List in the view for Create Action. The view just show field for Student Number, Title and description and nothing for the **Program and category Drop-down** list. I am not sure how to create SelectList and pass it to the view. I don't know if did it right.

```
    public class ServiceForm
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Student Number")]
        public int student_number { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Program")]
        public SelectList program { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        public SelectList category { get; set; }

    }
    public class Program
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string program_code { get; set; }
        public string program_desc { get; set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ProgramList> GetAllPrograms()
    {
        var s = ds.programs.OrderBy(m => m.program_code);
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProgramList>>(s);
    }

    private ServiceManager m = new ServiceManager();
    private ProgramManager pm = new ProgramManager();



    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        ServiceForm form = new ServiceForm();
        form.program = new SelectList(pm.GetAllPrograms(), "id", "program_code");
        List<SelectListItem> cat = new List<SelectListItem>();
        cat.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "General", Value = "General", Selected = true });
        cat.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Grades", Value = "Grades", Selected = false });
        cat.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Time Table", Value = "TimeTable", Selected = false });
        cat.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Zenit Account", Value = "Zenit", Selected = false });
        form.program = new SelectList(cat, cat.ElementAt(0));
        return View(form);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ServiceAdd newService)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var reform = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ServiceForm>(newService);
            reform.program = new SelectList(pm.GetAllPrograms(), "id", "program_code");
            List<SelectListItem> cat = new List<SelectListItem>();
            cat.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "General", Value = "General", Selected = true });
            cat.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Grades", Value = "Grades", Selected = false });
            cat.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Time Table", Value = "TimeTable", Selected = false });
            cat.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Zenit Account", Value = "Zenit", Selected = false });
            reform.program = new SelectList(cat, cat.ElementAt(0));
            return View(reform);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: ok...i will keep in mind for nxt time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model**

```
 public class ServiceForm
        {
            [Required]
            [Display(Name="Student Number")]
            public int student_number { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Display(Name="Program")]
            public SelectList Programs { get; set; }

            public string SelectedProgram { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Title")]
            public string title { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Description")]
            public string description { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Category")]
            public SelectList Categories{ get; set; }

            public string SelectedCategory { get; set; }

        }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{

    ServiceForm form = new ServiceForm();


    List<SelectListItem> cat = new List<SelectListItem>();
    cat.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "General", Value = "General", Selected = true });
    cat.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Grades", Value = "Grades", Selected = false });
    cat.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Time Table", Value = "TimeTable", Selected = false });
    cat.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Zenit Account", Value = "Zenit", Selected = false });
    form.Categories = cat; 

    //fill Programs property here...

    return View(form);
}
```

**View**

```
@model ServiceForm

@using(Html.BeginForm(...))
{
     @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Programs)
     @Html.DropDownFor(x => x.SelectedProgram , Model.Programs)
     @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Categories)
     @Html.DropDownFor(x => x.SelectedCategory, Model.Categories)

}
```

Comment: There is no point setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem`.   The selected item is the value of property `SelectedProgram` or `SelectedCategory` (the selected property is ignored)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var data = new ServiceForm();
    data.Categories = new SelectList({"1", "category1"}, {"2", "category2"});
    return View(data);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ServiceForm form)
{
     // validate the input and save
}
```

and in your Razor view you have something like this:

```
@model ServiceForm

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.DropDownFor(x => x.SelectedCategory, Model.Categories)
     <!-- ... other fields and labels -->
}
```

Comment: it shows invalid expression for data.Categories = new SelectList({"1", "category1"}, {"2", "category2"});